# Failed review audit for adding comment

Tags: bug, review-audit

I was just doing some first post reviews, and there was a post that simply asked a question with no attempt shown, so I was going to add a comment asking what the OP had tried, and apparently I failed the review audit since it was a 'high-quality post'. Is this a bug? Adding a comment isn't a 'review'.

Comment: "marked as duplicate by Lord_Farin, Matt Pressland, m0sa♦ 1 hour ago 

This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If those answers do not fully address your question, please edit this question to explain how it is different or ask a new question."- Actually no, that question does not have an answer.

Comment: It is true that it doesn't have an answer, but it is good to keep things all in the same place. It makes searching easier. Also, the question was closed by an SE employee. So the people who should know about this know about this. Assuming the SE employees communicate with one another...

Comment: Also on meta.SO: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188885

Comment: Well it's very impolite of them to just close the question without responding.